# Is there a better way to simplify this switch expression?

Tags: c++, performance

I have teaching myself c++, and was curious if anyone knows of a more efficient approach to this rock, paper, scissors game.

```
cout << "Pick 1, 2, or 3 for Rock, Paper, or Scissors\n> ";

// ...

int match = guess - botGuess;

switch (match) {

case 0:
    cout << tie;
    break;
case -1:
case 2:
    cout << lose;
    break;
case -2:
case 1:
    cout << win;
}
```

I simplified the 9 possible arrangements of the game into these 5 different cases, but I want to know if there's an even quicker way to play the game.

Comment: What is your measure of "efficiency"?  If you can't describe that, all you're doing is premature optimisation.

Comment: If equivalent then tie, if one of three win conditions then win, else lose. Makes four comparisons at most and has only three branches. It’s also much easier to follow.

Comment: I believe the question is simple but it can be used to show some optimization principles like the use of lookup tables.

Comment: Just to show how silly the question is, if a measure of efficiency is not defined ......    Assuming a value outside `1` - `3` is never picked or guessed, and that `win`, `lose` and `tie` all have the same type `t` , then `t *r[] = {&win, &lose, &tie}; cout << *r[match + 3*(match < 0) - 1];` will do.     This might be efficient according to some measure (which I won't try and specify), but is rather inefficient/sub-optimal in terms of measures that correlate with readability or maintainability.

Comment: Alternative approach using modulo arithmetic: https://godbolt.org/z/1Wc97EchE

Comment: Why do you need a quicker method, when your time is spent waiting for User input?

Answer (score 2):

For such small problem I'd use a lookup table instead of logic. It's `O(1)`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

constexpr std::array<const char*,3> names = {"Rock","Paper","Scissors"};
constexpr std::array<const char*,3> outcomes = {"Draw","win","Lose"}; 
constexpr std::array<std::array<int,3>,3> results = {{{0,2,1},{1,0,2},{2,1,0}}};

int main() {
    for ( int j=0; j<3; ++j ) {
        for ( int k=0; k<3; ++k ) {
            int result = results[j][k];
            std::cout << names[j] << " x " << names[k] << ": " << outcomes[result] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Rock x Rock: Draw
Rock x Paper: Lose
Rock x Scissors: win
Paper x Rock: win
Paper x Paper: Draw
Paper x Scissors: Lose
Scissors x Rock: Lose
Scissors x Paper: win
Scissors x Scissors: Draw
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/Gxa5vKsGv

Comment: To make this readable, I would have used an enum for Draw, Win, and Lose.  Then I would have organized the source for the lookup table as an actual table with rows and columns, and comments to label which are Rock, Paper, and Scissors.